# Selecting colors from Seaborn palette

Tags: python, seaborn

I have five distribution plots side by side and usually changed the color of each one using the color property.  However, now I want to use Seaborn's husl palette and I can't figure out how to apply a color from the palette to each chart. I'm pretty sure this is something simply I'm just over looking.

```
# sns.set(style="white", palette="muted", color_codes=True)  
sns.set(style="white", palette="husl", color_codes=True)

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=5, figsize=(15, 4))
sns.despine(left=True)

# Rating of 1
sns.distplot(df1[df1['rating']==1]['cost'], kde=False, color='c', ax=axes[0], axlabel="Rating of 1")

# Rating of 2
sns.distplot(df1[df1['rating']==2]['cost'], kde=False, color='k', ax=axes[1], axlabel='Rating of 2')

# Rating of 3
sns.distplot(df1[df1['rating']==3]['cost'], kde=False, color="g", ax=axes[2], axlabel='Rating of 3')

# Rating of 4
sns.distplot(df1[df1['rating']==4]['cost'], kde=False, color="m", ax=axes[3], axlabel='Rating of 4')

# Rating of 5
sns.distplot(df1[df1['rating']==5]['cost'], kde=False, color="b", ax=axes[4], axlabel='Rating of 5')

plt.setp(axes, yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seaborn provides an interface to the husl space via [`husl_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.husl_palette.html#seaborn.husl_palette). You may create a palette with as many colors as you have unique categories (here, "ratings"). Then, either index the palette or iterate over it. The latter is shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white")
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"cost" : np.random.randn(600),
                   "rating" : np.random.choice(np.arange(1,6), size=600)})

ratings = np.unique(df.rating.values)
palette = iter(sns.husl_palette(len(ratings)))

f, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(ratings), figsize=(15, 4))
sns.despine(left=True)

for (n, rat), ax in zip(df.groupby("rating"), axes):

    sns.distplot(rat["cost"], kde=False, color=next(palette), ax=ax, axlabel=f"Rating of {n}")

plt.setp(axes, yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, so simple!  For others, like myself, who are looking to specify the color for each chart here's how I did that.  Set the palette using `palette = sns.husl_palette(len(ratings))` and then in each plot use `color=palette[#]` where # is the index number you want to use.

Comment: @pheeper: I attempted this using a particular palette and received an error:

`sns.set_palette("Set1", 10)
colour_list = sns.husl_palette(10)`

Error: `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: '(0.8616090647292522, 0.536495730113334, 0.19548899031476086)'`